# Relation between Wigner quasi-probability distribution and statistical second-moment

Tags: density-matrix, continuous-variable, quantum-optics, wigner-function

Is there any relation between the Wigner quasi-probability distribution function $W$ and the statistical second-moment (also known as covariance matrix) of a density matrix of a continuous variable state, such as Gaussian state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like
$$W_{G}(\mathbf{r}) =\frac{2^{n}}{\pi^{n} \sqrt{\operatorname{Det} \sigma}} \mathrm{e}^{-(\mathbf{r}-\overline{\mathbf{r}})^{\top} \boldsymbol{\sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{r}-\overline{\mathbf{r}})},$$
where $W_{G}(\mathbf{r})$ is the Wigner function corresponding to a Gaussian state, $\mathbf{\sigma}$ its covariance matrix, and $\overline{r}$ the vector of first moments?

If yes, then, see, for example, Eqn. (4.50) of [Quantum Continuous Variables](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/bMItDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA1).

Comment: Thank you very much. It's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Great, can you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer then?